# How Would You Describe the Reasons Slices Are Used

Tags: server, systemd

Just been paying attention to systemctl status' branching structure. I realized I was making up stories to explain why it looked like that but had no clue of what it meant. I can't find much info on slices.

My story is that they are sliced off into isolation. And add security from reading the wrong address... that they probably constantly use the same virtually sliced addys.

[image: systemd branch view]

Can you give me some insight into what that illustration means from the OS perspective? Or your perspective...?

Comment: Please edit your question and include more details to describe the problem. As it is currently written, it is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: What is the function of a slice? It's hard to research when that is my question. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll think on it. I guess the position of the azure slice made me wonder wth Microsoft worked out by doing this. Looks like a powerful position though. Makes me feel like I don't have to do much to secure the thing.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Hard to research? [The first google hit has the answer.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.slice.html)

Comment: Your man page is better than mine. Thanks for the kind support. 

`$ man systemdctl`
`No manual entry for systemctld`

`$ man systemctld.slice`
`No manual entry for systemctld.slice`

Comment: Cool though... i had the right idea. Gioogle is just a front for an agency, I let being pay me for so often being useles.

Comment: @vidarlo turns out it is hard to research, cgroups would have been a better start

Comment: @user68186 proprietary azure, which led me to notice how the azure slice trumps all and an all seeing and and omnipotent orchestrator… which was why I found them curious. Ubuntu, but not a distro you can find anywhere.

Comment: @user68186 it’s about systemd. What id an official flavor of Ubuntu?

Comment: @vidarlo I don't use google. and the tag was [server]; meaning I'm in a terminal asking questions to a system that should be sufficient enough to to answer me. First google hits should be to StackExchange, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypothetical proposition “I want to make use of kernel cgroups, how do I do this in the new world order?” is used to explain how scope needs to be managed, and how slices play a role in this for systemd: [The New Control Group Interfaces](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/)

It highlights the ability to define constraints to members of a slice that trump the predefined allowances granted the the member’s author. Kind of like a cool handcuff feature.